# full wave rectifier is not rectifying the wave properly

Tags: transformer, rectifier, wave

the following rectifier does not create a wave that is rectified evenly. according to the books this should work when using a centre-tap transformer.

[image]

scales : (Y = 10ms/div) & (X = 5V / div)

peak values : (smaller pulse = 1.53 V) & (larger pulse = 3.59 V)

[image]

Software: NI MultiSim 13

Comment: Try putting a 100 ohm load on the diode outputs.

Comment: the transformer may not be working correctly.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast i did that and the wave just became smaller

Comment: I suggest looking at your transformer model. It's clearly not what you think

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast so you are saying that is not a centre tap transformer

Comment: Well, probably. I dunno. I'm just saying that the model of a symmetrical CT transformer shouldn't behave like that. Try the obvious, and look at the transformer outputs.

Answer (score 1):

[image: I think it should be like this..]

It should be like this i think, works good for me, wave is ok :)